# logrotate: error opening (No such file or directory)

Tags: apache-httpd, logrotate, logs

I got an error message. This is sent to my mail box automatically.

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error opening /var/log/apache2/access.log.1.gz: No such file or directory
error: error opening /var/log/apache2/myhost/access.log.1.gz: No such file or directory
```

I also check my `/var/log/apache2/*` and `/var/log/apache2/myhost/*` those directories. There aren't the file `access.log.1.gz`, but definitely a file `access.log.1` existed on the directories. I just start to configure `logrotate` this tool for my log file management and my apache have run for a long period, at least 30 log files existed on my directories. Currently, I have no idea why it happened like this.

My `/etc/logrotate` is as below:

```
/var/log/apache2/*.log {
     daily
     missingok
     rotate 10
     compress
     delaycompress
#    notifempty
     create 640 root adm
     sharedscripts
     postrotate
                 /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null;
     endscript
     prerotate
             if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                     run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
             fi; \
     endscript
}
/var/log/apache2/myhost/*.log {
     daily
     missingok
     rotate 10
     compress
     delaycompress
#    notifempty
     create 640 root adm
     sharedscripts
     postrotate
             /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
     endscript
     prerotate
             if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                     run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
             fi; \
     endscript
}
```

Comment: What do you have in `/etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate` ? You should probably not do it twice, nor `apache2 reload` in fact but this is what you are doing because of the two types of logs where in fact they pertain to the same "system" (Apache). Also you seem to miss a '*' it sould be `*.log` twice not just `.log`. You can also launch `logrotate` with the `-d` option to see what it is doing.

Comment: Hi, I mark one of them due to your saying that the /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate is not existed actually. What do you mean *.log and .log? Here I do not know clearly. I run "logrotate -d apache2" this command. Shows up as below: "removing old log /var/log/apache2/myhost/access.log.1.gz
error: error opening /var/log/apache2/myhost/access.log.1.gz: No such file or directory." 
I check my directory and get list which there are access.log, access.log.1, access.log.2.gz, access.log.3.gz, access.log.4.gz and etc... But, there aren't anyone called as "access.log.1.gz". Is this to make it stop?

Comment: Hi, I got the recent message on my mail box.
<code>
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
error: error opening /var/log/apache2/access.log.1.gz: No such file or directory
error: error opening /var/log/apache2/myhost/access.log.1.gz: No such file or directory
</code> 
It miss the first one compressed file only and then don't go through to do the next one. I want to know how to compress the first one either. This may help to let it know and continue to run the script.

Comment: If your current data is not important I would recommend starting from scratch. Stop Apache, delete all Apache log files, restart Apache, and let logrotate run normally. Otherwise to compress `access.log.1` just do `gzip access.log.1`

Answer (score 1):

I got fixed. 
There are two places modified by my new configuration. 
Now, the /var/log/apache2/myhost/ is like below without any alone "access.log.1" and "error.log.1".

What is my configuration on my /etc/logrotate.d as below. I get rid of asterisk and make their name specificlly. Otherwise, I comment "delaycompress" this directive.

    `/var/log/apache2/myhost/access.log /var/log/apache2/myhost/error.log {
            daily
            missingok
            rotate 2
            compress
    #       delaycompress
    #       notifempty
            create 640 root adm
            sharedscripts
            postrotate
            /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
            endscript
    }`

Here I add a file /etc/logrotate.conf. I comment out "compress" this also. Then, I execute "sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache2". This mean to force it to implement this execution. The result is good. Thanks all.

`# see "man logrotate" for details
    # rotate log files weekly
    weekly`

```
# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# packages drop log rotation information into this directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# no packages own wtmp, or btmp -- we'll rotate them here
/var/log/wtmp {
missingok
monthly
create 0664 root utmp
rotate 1
}

/var/log/btmp {
missingok
monthly
create 0660 root utmp
rotate 1
}

# system-specific logs may be configured here
</code>
```